# Confluent Sink Connectors - How Many is Too Many

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

1. I want to use Confluent sink connector to update Postgres database on remote servers.  On average day we may have 1000-2000 messages (updates).  Is it "legitimate" to create hundreds of sink connectors to copy those messages to all the remote servers? Having that many sink connectors is normal?
2. Is it possible to tell the sink connector to "spread" their work so not all 100's of connectors will push the changes to the remote servers at the same time?
   Should "timestamp.delay.interval.ms" be used for that?

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify why you are expecting to "create hundreds of sink connectors "?

Comment: How are the "remote servers" structured? If they are distributed across regions, you only need to create as many connectors as there are region masters. The slaves should be replicating off of the master.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In theory you could have one connector per target server. One connector can stream data from multiple topics to a single server. You may find yourself increasing the number of connectors if configuration varies by topic (such as different primary key column names, differing `insert.mode` requirements, etc) - and that is totally valid ("legitimate" )
2. Each **connector** will spawn one, or more, **tasks** to carry out the work. If one connector is streaming data for multiple target objects it can parallelise that work with concurrent tasks *if you want it to*. If you want to stream data in a serial fashion so that there is just the one connection to the database then set `tasks.max` accordingly.

To learn more about the connector/task execution model see [docs](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/devguide.html#connectors-and-tasks) and [tutorial video](https://rmoff.dev/kafka-connect-zero-to-hero).

Comment: Thanks.  If I keep it at tasks.max =1 the order of execution will be the order the tables are listed in the table.whitelist?

Comment: I don't know if it's deterministic; you'd need to check the source code. https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/tree/master/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/jdbc